# Swift Modify notification configurations

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, nsnotificationcenter

I have a quick question about Swift I cannot manage to answer by reading docs and forums:

- Is it possible to modify notification configurations directly into an app? I mean, would it be possible to automatically (via code) modify the notification configurations (on/off, banners, ...) of my application or another application? Can the user give the right to the application to do so?

  - If yes, what object should I use?
  - If no, why and is it possible to bypass this limitation ?

I am very interested in learning more about it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the notification settings through code. You have to go to settings to change that. There is no possible way to bypass this, probably you have to jailbreak (But I'm not sure, what you should do to implement this feature).

The only thing, you can control via code is the content and appearance of your app's notification. You can use the [Notification Content Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications?language=objc) for that.

Comment: Too bad. Is there a way I can present my idea to Apple directly then ? Thank you very much for the prompt reply

Comment: @Joseph Yes, there can be private APIs available through which you can probably achieve this, for that you may need to contact apple and explain your idea https://developer.apple.com/support/

Comment: @Joseph There are private APIs used by some apps which are approved by apple (like Nike app), so you probably want to contact them, because probably no one knows how to implement this other than the Apple API engineers.

Comment: Awesome. Will contact them directly. Thank you very much for your support